# How do I change the tile type for one area of the map?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium, tile-layer

The whole map has a TileLayer = 'OpenStreetMap'. How to change the Title Layer only for the area indicated by the polygon?

```py
import folium

X1 = 61.70029083832628
Y1 = 27.24609375
X2 = 61.68987220046
Y2 = 27.26806640625

mapObj = folium.Map(location=[X1, Y1], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=14)

folium.Polygon(
    [(X1, Y1), (X2, Y1), (X2, Y2), (X1, Y2)],
    color='red',
    weight=4
).add_to(mapObj)

mapObj
```

[image: Сurrently]

For example, so that the polygon has TileLayer = 'Stamen Watercolor'

[image: Result]

Comment: For plain JS Leaflet there is `leaflet-boundary-canvas` (see https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas) plugin that just that. It's a bit old but works also with the latest Leaflet 1.9.3.